# Series of letters used by typists to indicate error

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the series of letters used by typewriter typists to indicate that a typo has been made? It was formed by typing the letters on the row or column of the keyboard, and is I think split into two words.

Comment: Are you referring to the use of (sic)??

Comment: I'm wondering if the querent is confusing 'typewriter typists' with 'hot lead/Linotype typesetters'; hot lead typesetters used to use `etaion shrdlu` to finish a cast for a line with a typo in it - such slugs were easily recognizable, and discarded.

Comment: (_I say "used to use" because very little typesetting - if any - nowadays is done with hot lead; it's mostly [all?] digital._)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yep, could be what you say and yes, typesetting is now digital.

Comment: Perhaps qwerty12345 means the marks subeditors used to make in the margin next to the line containing the error. Wikipedia has only ^h^h^h^h, meaning 'delete the latter four letters. Their example is:  Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman. I think that's a fairly recent convention. Try Googling "proofreading symbols pdf" then switch to Image View. Are THOSE what you're after?

Comment: Yes! I was looking for the term `etaion shrudlu`! Thank you!

Comment: So now you give it the green checkmark to indicate that you are accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for etaoin shrudlu, as posted in the comments by @Jeff Zeitlin.

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etaoin_shrdlu)